# Data model for inconsistent data on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am pretty new to NoSQL and Cassandra but I was told by my architecture committee to use this. I just want to understand how to convert the RDBMS model to noSQL.

I have a database where user needs to import data from an excel or csv file into the database. This file may have different columns each time.

For example in the excel file data might look something like this:

```
Name| AName| Industry| Interest | Pint |Start Date | End date

x | 111-121 | IT | 2 | 1/1/2011 | 1/2/2011

x | 111-122 | hotel | 1 | "" | ""

y| 111-1000 | IT | 2 | 1/1/2011 | 1/2/2011
```

After we upload this the next excel file might look

```
Name| AName| Industry| Interest | Pint |Start Date | isTrue | isNegative

x | 111-121 | IT | 2 | 1/1/2011 | 1/2/2011 | yes | no

x | 111-122 | hotel | 1 | "" | no | no

y| 111-1000 |health | 2 | 1/1/2010 | yes|""
```

I would not know in advance what columns I am going to create when importing data. I am totally confused with noSQL and unable to understand how handle this on how to import data when I don't know the table structure

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basic fact that a column family (cassandra for "table") is made up of rows.  Each row has a row key and some number of key/value pairs (called columns).  For a particular column in a row the name of the column is the key for the pair and the value of the column is the value of the pair.  Just because you have a column by some name in one row does not necessarily mean you'll have a column by that name in any other row.

Internally, row keys, column names and column values are stored as byte arrays and you'll need to use serializers to convert program data to the byte arrays and back again.

It's up to you as to how you define the row key, column name and column value.

One approach would be to have a row in the CF correspond to a row from Excel.  You'd have to identify the one Excel column that will provide a unique id and store that in the row key.  The remained of the Excel columns can get stored in cassandra columns, one-to-one.  This lets you be very flexible on most column names, but you have to have a unique key value somewhere.  The unique key requirement will always hold for any storage scheme you use.

There are other storage schemes, but they all boil down to you defining in the Excel what your row key is and how you break the Excel data into key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some noSQL patterns and I highly suggest reading "Building on Quicksand" by Pat Helland

some good patterns(with or without using PlayOrm)...
http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Patterns-Page/

Comment: Your link is broken.